# Is it possible that old Java 6 didn't get some "array out of bounds exception"?

Tags: java

I have an old application that was running on an old piece of software/hardware system on Java 6, which has been restored decompiled and running on Java 11.
Among the many adaptations and corrections, I found an "array out of bounds exception", which I fixed.
The funny part is that the same code, with the same data causing the exception on Java 11, runs (apparently) flawlessly on Java 6!

Now the code is too complex to report it all here, but the problem boils down to a couple of arrays, allocated for **N** elements as in `array = new float[N];` and accessed later as `array[N] = value;`

This is obviously an error, and that code is enclosed in a `try...catch` in the caller method, which triggers the exception, in Java 11. That's just **perfect**.

However, the unpatched code with Java 6 doesn't trigger the exception. The running hardware/software system is too old to be debugged, but I've got reports that it still runs **apparently flawlessly**.

Is there any assessed reason for it? I'm puzzled...

Comment: It's not totally impossible, that some complex combination of steps leads to wrongly excluded boundary checks where they would be needed, but I still find it pretty unlikely to happen as late as Java 6.

Comment: What is the output of the stacktrace in java 11?

Comment: No, there was never a java version where this _did not_ throw an out of bounds exception. Most likely explanation: Your decompiler messed up. They aren't perfect.

Comment: If this “complex” code is using multiple threads, it’s possible that different thread visibility semantics are responsible.  Reassignment of a non-volatile array field might have been visible to different threads sooner (or later) in Java 6 than in Java 11.

Comment: @rzwitserloot No idea about that, used JD-GUI and everything else made sense so far. :shrug:

Comment: @VGR This is an interesting issue. However, this array allocation and thread creation follow a user selection, so this happens only once. I know that "complex" is vague, but I've been left myself with a bunch of "lasagna" code (yes, not "spaghetti"...) with an enormous amount of messy layers...

Comment: @DavidKariuki the stacktrace is as simple as this `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 189 out of bounds for length 189
 at com.example.appl.IO.file.USBDumper.readFile(USBDumper.java:521)
 at com.example.appl.IO.file.USBDumper.dumpToUsb(USBDumper.java:243)
 at com.example.appl.gui.ExportThread.run(ExportThread.java:125)`

Comment: Can you really be sure that neither `N` nor `array` changes in-between or that the evaluation of `value` does not fail in a different way even before writing to `array[N]`? Or that there is no conditional in between causing this statement not to be executed? Mind that even if this statement would be executed without causing an exception, the array still would be one `float` smaller than intended which would affect the behavior of subsequent operations.

Comment: @Holger The thread is executed to completion, approximately `N` is the number of lines read from a text file (that cannot be changed, has been saved in a separate dedicated operation); the `array` is a sample of data in those lines (like one out of 8); when the array is filled up the thread ends correctly and `array` data is saved to a new file. Error code was simply adding one element more than available. Every other UI thread is waiting for this one to end or abort. I can't believe I succeeded with the synthesis of this horrible mess :D